# Batch unzip files in child folders, then copy specific files to network folder based on number in file name

Tags: batch-file

I am a serious newbie at creating batch files and am hoping someone can help me.  One of our staff receives zipped pdf docs by email, which she copies to a folder on her desktop.  Within that folder, I would like for her to run a batch script that will

A.  Unzip the zipped contents into a network directory, i.e. \server\contracts
Under this directory, the process will create folders for each group of contracts, i.e. \server\contracts\Masterson (The name of this will be same as zipped file name).

B.  Then the batch process should copy a select few of the pdf documents into a network directory based on the filename.  Each file contains a number, which will go in the following manner:  Masterson + 1.pdf >> \server\contracts\Item1 and \server\contracts\Item2, etc.  Masterson + 1.pdf will go into \server\contracts\Item1 without a folder name, as will Paisley + 1 certificate.pdf and Johnsonville + 1 document.pdf.

The problem is that the companies do not follow instructions and the number can be at the beginning, middle, or end of the file name.  Also, unfortunately, there are spaces in the name of the zipped file and the pdf documents.  Currently, we are only copying 4 filenames into separate directories for other people to review and validate.

Below is what I did so far looking around this site:

```
@Echo off

SETLOCAL
for /R "delims=\\server\contracts\RECEIVED 2017-18 APPLICATION" %%I in   
("*.zip") do (
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -o"%%~dpnI" "%%~fI" 
)


rem setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
CLS

::The Input Folder
set "InputFolder=C:\Users\eartha.kitt\Desktop\Test"

::The Output Folders
set "Output1=\\server\contracts\ITEM 1 17-18 CERTS"
set "Output6=\\server\contracts\ITEM 6 SIGNATURES"
set "Output8A=\\server\contracts\ITEM 8A 17-18 CALENDARS"
set "Output8B=\\server\contracts\ITEM 8B 16-17 REVISED CALENDARS"
set "Output8a=\\server\contracts\ITEM 8A 17-18 CALENDARS"
set "Output8b=\\server\contracts\ITEM 8B 16-17 REVISED CALENDARS"

::The extensions to wait
set "extensions=*.pdf"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:Loop
cls
echo Waiting for file ...
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%a in ('dir /b /s %InputFolder%\%extensions%  
2^>nul') do (
rem for /r %%a in in (%InputFolder%\%extensions% 2^>nul') do (
set "Fichier=%%a"
echo Treating _^> %%a
if "!Fichier:~0,-2!"==" 1" COPY "%%~a" %Output1%
if "!Fichier:~0,-2!"==" 6" COPY "%InputFolder%\~%%a" %Output6%
if "!Fichier:~0,-3!"=="8A" COPY "%InputFolder%\%%a" %Output8A%
if "!Fichier:~0,-3!"=="8B" COPY "%InputFolder%\%%a" %Output8B%
if "!Fichier:~0,-3!"=="8a" COPY "%InputFolder%\%%a" %Output8a%
if "!Fichier:~0,-3!"=="8b" COPY "%InputFolder%\%%a" %Output8b%

::Waiting ~5 seconds
ping localhost -n 6 >nul
)
::Return to the loop
goto:Loop
```

Of course this doesn't work.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Well - bravo for the attempt! And so close...

Let's take the first part

```
for /R "delims=\\server\contracts\RECEIVED 2017-18 APPLICATION" %%I in ("*.zip") do (
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -o"%%~dpnI" "%%~fI"
```

)

What's wrong here is that the `delims` clause is only usable in `for /f`. `for /r` always delivers the entire filename to the metavariable `%%I`.

*On my system* I use `%server%\u` for testing - `u` is a shared resource on the server assigned to `U:\` on `server`.

```dos
for /R "\\%server%\u\contracts\RECEIVED 2017-18 APPLICATION" %%I IN ("*.zip") do (
 "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -o"%%~dpnI" "%%~fI"
```

worked happily for me - delivering the extracted files to "u:\contracts\RECEIVED 2017-18 APPLICATION"

The second part of your code is examining  "C:\Users\eartha.kitt\Desktop\Test" not "\%server%\u\contracts\RECEIVED 2017-18 APPLICATION" - very sensibly assigned to a variablename for easy adjustment.

Here's my modified code:

```dos
SET "terminatefilename=stop.txt"

DEL "%terminatefilename%" 2>nul
rem setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
CLS

::The Input Folder
set "InputFolder=C:\Users\eartha.kitt\Desktop\Test"
set "InputFolder=\\%server%\u\contracts\RECEIVED 2017-18 APPLICATION"

::The Output Folders
set "Output1=\\%server%\u\contracts\ITEM 1 17-18 CERTS"
set "Output6=\\%server%\u\contracts\ITEM 6 SIGNATURES"
set "Output8A=\\%server%\u\contracts\ITEM 8A 17-18 CALENDARS"
set "Output8B=\\%server%\u\contracts\ITEM 8B 16-17 REVISED CALENDARS"

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%b IN ('set output') DO MD "%%c" 2>nul

::The extensions to wait
set "extensions=*.pdf"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:Loop
cls
echo Waiting for file ...
for /f "delims=|" %%a in ('dir /b /s "%InputFolder%\%extensions%" 2^>nul') do (
 rem for /r %%a in in (%InputFolder%\%extensions% 2^>nul') do (
 SET "copied="
 echo Treating _^> %%a

 REM OPTION 1 - Key string must be at end-of name part

 set "Fichier=%%~Na"
 if /i "!Fichier:~0,-2!"==" 1" COPY "%%a" "%Output1%"&SET "copied=Y"
 if /i "!Fichier:~0,-2!"==" 6" COPY "%%a" "%Output6%"&SET "copied=Y"
 if /i "!Fichier:~0,-3!"==" 8A" COPY "%%a" "%Output8A%"&SET "copied=Y"
 if /i "!Fichier:~0,-3!"==" 8B" COPY "%%a" "%Output8B%"&SET "copied=Y"
 REM OPTION 2 - Key string may be anywhere in filename

 IF NOT DEFINED copied (
  echo "%%~na"|FINDSTR /i /L /C:" 8B" >NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 COPY "%%a" "%Output8B%"&SET "copied=Y"
 )
 IF NOT DEFINED copied (
  echo "%%~na"|FINDSTR /i /L /C:" 8A" >NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 COPY "%%a" "%Output8A%"&SET "copied=Y"
 )
 IF NOT DEFINED copied (
  echo "%%~na"|FINDSTR /i /L /C:" 6" >NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 COPY "%%a" "%Output6%"&SET "copied=Y"
 )
 IF NOT DEFINED copied (
  echo "%%~na"|FINDSTR /i /L /C:" 1" >NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 COPY "%%a" "%Output1%"&SET "copied=Y"
 )
)



::Waiting ~5 seconds
timeout 6 >NUL

:: Test for exit
IF EXIST "%terminatefilename%" DEL "%terminatefilename%"&GOTO :EOF 

::Return to the loop
goto:Loop
```

First, I set up `terminatefilename` so that creating this file will terminate the batch (it's an infinite loop by design in your code)

Next, I overrode your `inputfolder` name to suit my system.

Then the output directories. I adjusted their names to suit my system. Note that batch is largely case-insensitive, so setting `Output8A` and `Output8a` is setting the *same* variable. The only time that batch commands are case-sensitive is the metavariable (loop-control variable) in a `for` statement.

Then I inserted a line to create the destination directories. This uses a `set` command to list the variables starting `output` in the format `Output1=\\%server%\u\contracts\ITEM 1 17-18 CERTS` (where `server` will have been resolved). The command reads the output of the `set` command, uses `=` as the delimiter and assigns `output1` to `%%b` and `\\%server%\u\contracts\ITEM 1 17-18 CERTS` to `%%c`. We want to make sure the directory `%%c` exists, so we make it with an `md` command and ignore complaints that it already exists with `2>nul`.

Next the `for/f`. `for /f` reads each line of `(thisfilename)` or `("this literal value")` or `('the output of this command')` but when you need to read a from a file whose name must be double-quoted beacuse it contains spaces, then the syntax is `for /f "usebackq"...` `(idontknow)` or `("this filename containing spaces")` or `('ive no idea whatever')` or **(`the output of this command`)**

So there's no need to use `usebackq` -- in fact, it's counterproductive.

The `delims=|` is optional and could be replaced by `delims=` as the output of a `dir` command will never contain `|` (illegal in a file or directoryname). You **do** need the `delims` clause however, as the default delimiters include <kbd>Space</kbd> and the default `tokens` is `1` so only the first string of each line output up to the first space will be assigned to `%%a`.

Hmm - you've `rem`med-out a `for/r`. Sadly, the target directory in the `for /r` can't be a metavariable.

Next, I've cleared a `copied` flag saying "so far, this file has not been copied"

Next, set `fichier` to the name-part only of the filename. Since you are using `.pdf` as a filter, each name output by the `for/f` will be a full-filename, ending in `.pdf`

Next, almost-correct with the battery of `if` statements. The `/i` makes the comparison case-insensitive so that it will cope with both `8a` and `8A`. The strings on both sides of the `==` must be *identical* to pass the `==` test, so you need a 3-character string in the `8` tests.

You've evidently been experimenting with the `copy` command and trying to feed it with appropriate strings. `%%~a` strips `%%a` of any enclosing quotes. `%%a` won't have enclosing quotes - just the fullfilename, so this does nothing in this instance. `%InputFolder%\~%%a` concatenates the values from `InputFolder`,"\~" and `%%a` - which means "%inputfolder%\~%inputfolder%\*filenameandextension of %%a*". The last two would be resolved to the same, bar the `~`.

Since the **entire** filename is contained in `%%a`, all that's needed for the sourcefile is `"%%a"` - quoted as it will probably contain spaces.

Well - the destination directory (we've already established it with the `for /f...%%b`) can also contain spaces, so it needs to be quoted, too.

I've then set the flag `copied` to `Y` if the line took effect. Actually, it can be set to any non-empty value as the whole object is to interpret whether or not it exists with an `if defined` statement to bypass any later attempts to copy the same file (remember - `copied` is cleared for each file)

Now - the second option. This is actually a more powerful detector of the required target strings than is the substring version, and will detect the target string anywhere in the filename.

If you `echo` the name-part only of the file `%%~na` into a `findstr`, then set to `findstr` to look for the `/L` literal string `/i` case-insensitive `c:"some literal string"` and output ny matches found to *nowhere* (`>nul`) then `findstr` will set `errorlevel` to `0` if found and `1` otherwise. (the `/L` is superfluous here, I use it habitually to remind me I'm working with literal strings, not regular expressions)

`If errorlevel n` will be true if `errorlevel` is currently `n` or greater than `n`, so if the string is found, we do the copy and set the `copied` flag as before.

I reversed the order of tests because it was easier for me to do using the editor I use.

Now - there's a downside to this approach. It's a double-edged sword. Since the target string is detected *wherever* it appears in the filename, `whatever whatever 10 something something.pdf` will pass the test for `1` because <kbd>Space</kbd>1 appears in its name.

When the loop has finished, use `timeout` to wait, redirecting the output to `nul` to make it pipe down. Note that your delay was inside the `for` loop - so it would have waited 6 seconds after processing each file, not 6 seconds after processing an entire batch.

Finally, if you create `terminatefilename` from anothe `cmd` instance, the batch will exit cleanly and kill `terminatefilename` for you. Much cleaner than control-c.

A last note: Since you are `copy`ing the file, not `MOVE`ing it, it will still exist in the same place presumably after the 6 seconds has elapsed and will be endlessly copied and recopied. You'd probably need to make adjustments to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Wow, in less than a day and with comments no less!!!!!!  You're awesome.  I will make the necessary changes, test it, and post back.

Comment: Alas, it didn't work and there were no error messages.  It's like it didn't find the files in order to copy them to the folders.  The command program stays open and keeps blinking.

Comment: I am getting File Not Found at the end of the run.  When users copy the zipped file to the Eartha_Kitt folder on the desktop, the file is zipped.  The directory where the batch file is located is C:\Users\eartha.kitt\Desktop\Test

Comment: If I click all the way to the pdf documents, the directory structure is like this:  C:\Users\eartha.kitt\Desktop\Test\Masterson + MC.zip\Masterson + MC\Masterson + 1.pdf

Comment: Help Magoo!  I've been playing around with the code and I am still unable to make this work.  I see where the code is evaluating each file but at the end it says that the "File Not Found"